# Can webpack bundle js files without require or import? Q2: Why is a graph needed?

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, require

Im new to webpack and as i understand it, it will create a graph starting on the entry(ies) point and based on the require commands specified in each script thereafter.

**Question 1:**
I was wondering if there's a way for webpack to bundle up a bunch of specified files ( say all the files in a folder and all its subfolders ) somehow.

**Question 2**
Im not sure why it needs to create a graph to begin with. Wouldnt it be enough to keep a record of each library needed and only include it once at the final bundle.js script? Why a graph?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**

This could probably help you in defining entry point as a directory using `glob` npm package

```
var glob = require("glob");
// ...
entry: glob.sync("./test/**/*Spec.js")
```

To followup more on this, check out this github issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370

However, turns out entry takes an array as well, where the first file will be used for bundling and the rest are appended to the end of `bundle.js`

```
entry: ['index.js', 'otherEntry.js', ...]
```

Check out this Medium article for a little more on the multiple entries.
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9

**`3. “entry” — String Vs Array Vs Object`** section

**Question 2**

**DISCLAIMER**: Totally personal opinion

I am not entirely sure why a graph approach was taken up but I started to come to terms with the decision due to the fact that, your whole application irrespective of how complex it could be will be executed from a starting point. Be it one entry point or multiple entry points, all your code will start from a specific function / module. Just like how everything executes from `main` in many programming languages. I could be entirely wrong but it's just a thought.

Someone who has done more research with `Webpack` or is a contributor, please edit this answer. I would like to know the exact reason as well.

Comment: Exactly, having a starting point makes a lot of sense. There clearly was a need for a graph as the people that made this are very smart and wouldnt arbitrarily go with that decision but the why still eludes me. I think i have a possible explanation. Some things might be required before others and therefore putting them in one file might not be enough, putting them in the correct order might also be instrumental to things working and therefore a graph is one way to keep track of that.

Comment: Hmm, upon working with it i realised that adding multiple entry points doesnt mean that they re in the same scope. So if one entry point has a class A and the other a class B, they cant see each other's class. It seems like each entry point defines a "package" of sorts.

Comment: You COULD add the class directly to the window object but it seems like when you define a class in webpack thats not what it does at all. This is what happens if you execute a script in the browser but it looks like webpack wraps the context around a block of sorts.. So using glob to bundle multiple js files together works.. only if they re unrelated to each other.

Comment: Oh is it, I thought multiple entry points is just going to be like generating a `bundle.js` with the first entry point and appending all the other entry point graphs at the bottom of the generated bundle.js. Either way don't you think the purpose of multiple entry points is to stitch scripts that are un-related to each other?